How to put this grid to a 1 column list on mobile
I have this menu grid with a center text and other menu options around it and I want it to work on mobile as a single line grid. I want the center large text space around which the rest of the grid elements are positioned around to disappear on mobile too.
So far I made a media query with the max width 768px and set the grid column to 1 (100%) column.
The problem is that somehow I get two columns instead of one if I move the window under 768px (and the center text which I dont know how to make it disappear doesn't disappear too).
I tried with this css code:
    .container {      display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;     grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    gap: 30px;     align-items: center; 
`
In the center of the grid I put a larger column with this code and the rest of the grid elements are around the center:
`    .kozepe {
     grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 3;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;`

My media query:
`    @media (max-width: 768px) {
`    .container {
`        display: grid;
`        grid-template-columns:100%;
`        grid-template-rows: auto;
`    }
`    }`

All the grid items have this property:
````.item {`
`    font-family: "Freeman", sans-serif;
`    font-weight: 800;
`    font-size: 2rem;
`    display: block;
`    text-decoration: none;
`>   color: black;`
``

    <body>
`    <div class="flex">
``    <div class="container">
``        <a href="zene.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item "><div>Zene</div></a>
`        <a href="gta.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item kozep"><div>Grand Theft Auto</div>   </a>
`        <a href="gitár.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item"><div>Gitár</div></a>
`        <a href="számítógép.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item"><div>Számítógép</div></a>
`        <a href="kozep.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item kozepe"><div>Nézd meg ezt csináltam ma jujj de örülök neki!!!</div></a>
``        <a href="fotózás.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item"><div>Fotózás</div></a>
`        <a href="útjaim.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item"><div>Útjaim</div></a>
`        <a href="sport.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item"><div>Sport</div></a>
``        <a href="képesítéseim.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item"><div>Képesítéseim</div></a>
``        <a href="hobbijaim.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item kozep"><div>Hobbijaim</div></a>
``        <a href="valami.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item"><div>Valami</div>
`        </div>`
        
    
`    </div>
`</div>
`</body>`

``


Can you put your code thro' a validator and correct the problems in the HTML first.

To get that central text into the single column at the same relative position (i.e. 5th) on a smaller viewport, just tell it to have column 1 and row 5.
If you want it somewhere else in the row-order then alter that row setting.


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  gap: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  /* In the center of the grid I put a larger column with this code and the rest of the grid elements are around the center:*/
}

.kozepe {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 3;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
  }
  .kozepe {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 5;
  }
}

.item {
  font-family: "Freeman", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
<div class="flex">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="zene.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item ">
      <div>Zene</div>
    </a>
    <a href="gta.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item kozep">
      <div>Grand Theft Auto</div>
    </a>
    <a href="gitár.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item">
      <div>Gitár</div>
    </a>
    <a href="számítógép.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item">
      <div>Számítógép</div>
    </a>
    <a href="kozep.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item kozepe">
      <div>Nézd meg ezt csináltam ma jujj de örülök neki!!!</div>
    </a>
    <a href="fotózás.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item">
      <div>Fotózás</div>
    </a>
    <a href="útjaim.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item">
      <div>Útjaim</div>
    </a>
    <a href="sport.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item">
      <div>Sport</div>
    </a>
    <a href="képesítéseim.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item">
      <div>Képesítéseim</div>
    </a>
    <a href="hobbijaim.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item kozep">
      <div>Hobbijaim</div>
    </a>
    <a href="valami.html" style="text-decoration:none;" class="item">
      <div>Valami</div>
    </a>
  </div>


</div>



